# Can I find distances between arrays in PostgreSQL using <->?

Tags: sql, postgresql, knn

As far as I understood from [this](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-12-implementing-k-nearest-neighbor-space-partitioned-generalized-search-tree-indexes/) article, you can find nearest neighbors using <-> distance operator when working with geometric data types:

```
SELECT name, location --location is point
FROM geonames
ORDER BY location <-> '(29.9691,-95.6972)'
LIMIT 5;
```

You can also get some optimizations using SP-GiST indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_spgist_geonames_location ON geonames USING spgist(location);
```

But I can't find anything about using <-> operator with arrays in the documentation. If I were to perform same queries using `double precision[]` instead of `point`, for example, would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, we can't. For example, I've got a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  loc double precision[]
);
```

And I want to query documents from it, ordering by distance,

```
SELECT loc FROM test ORDER BY loc <-> ARRAY[0, 0, 0, 0]::double precision[];
```

It doesn't work:

```
 Query Error: error: operator does not exist: double precision[] <-> double precision[]
```

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) has no mention of <-> for arrays as well. I found a workaround in accepted answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792202/postgres-index-on-cosine-similarity-of-float-arrays-for-one-to-many-search) question, but it poses some limitations, especially on array's length. Although there is an [article](https://habr.com/ru/post/503402/) (written in Russian), which suggests a workaround on array size limitation. Creation of sample table:

```
import postgresql

def setup_db():
    db = postgresql.open('pq://user:pass@localhost:5434/db')
    db.execute("create extension if not exists cube;")
    db.execute("drop table if exists vectors")
    db.execute("create table vectors (id serial, file varchar, vec_low cube, vec_high cube);")
    db.execute("create index vectors_vec_idx on vectors (vec_low, vec_high);")
```

Element insertion:

```
query = "INSERT INTO vectors (file, vec_low, vec_high) VALUES ('{}', CUBE(array[{}]), CUBE(array[{}]))".format(
            file_name,
            ','.join(str(s) for s in encodings[0][0:64]),
            ','.join(str(s) for s in encodings[0][64:128]),
        )
db.execute(query)
```

Element querying:

```
import time
import postgresql
import random

db = postgresql.open('pq://user:pass@localhost:5434/db')

for i in range(100):
    t = time.time()
    encodings = [random.random() for i in range(128)]

    threshold = 0.6
    query = "SELECT file FROM vectors WHERE sqrt(power(CUBE(array[{}]) <-> vec_low, 2) + power(CUBE(array[{}]) <-> vec_high, 2)) <= {} ".format(
        ','.join(str(s) for s in encodings[0:64]),
        ','.join(str(s) for s in encodings[64:128]),
        threshold,
    ) + \
            "ORDER BY sqrt(power(CUBE(array[{}]) <-> vec_low, 2) + power(CUBE(array[{}]) <-> vec_high, 2)) ASC LIMIT 1".format(
                ','.join(str(s) for s in encodings[0:64]),
                ','.join(str(s) for s in encodings[64:128]),
            )
    print(db.query(query))
    print('inset time', time.time() - t, 'ind', i)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [article linked in the OP](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-12-implementing-k-nearest-neighbor-space-partitioned-generalized-search-tree-indexes/), the author seems to be using [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/), an extension that does define a `<->` operator  to return the 2D distance between two geometries.

Documentation of the `<->` operator:
https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html